# How to determine an existing oracle database connection in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, database-connection

Assuming that I call the method below with the right credentials:

```
private bool Connect(string username, string password)
    {
        string CONNSTRING = "Provider = MSDAORA; Data Source = ISDQA; User ID = {0}; Password = {1};";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        string strCon = string.Format(CONNSTRING, username, password);
        conn.ConnectionString = strCon;
        bool isConnected = false;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
                isConnected = true;
        }//try
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErr.Text = "Connection error";
        }//catch
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }//finally

        return isConnected;
    }
```

I have successfully open the connection in my method below:

```
private bool ValidateUserCode(string usercode)
{
    UserAccountDefine def = new UserAccountDefine();
    UserAccountService srvc = new UserAccountService();
    UserAccountObj obj = new UserAccountObj();

    bool returnVal = false;
    bool isValid = Connect(def.DB_DUMMY_USERCODE, def.DB_DUMMY_PASSWORD);
    if (isValid)
    {
        obj.SQLQuery = string.Format(def.SQL_LOGIN, usercode.ToLower(), DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyy"));
        DataTable dt = srvc.Execute(obj, CRUD.READALL);
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            returnVal = true;
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

The question is how can I determine the connection status in `ValidateUserCode()` method?
How can I close it afterwards?

Note:
I explicitly declare the string variables in `UserAccountDefine();` so you don't have to worry about that.

I already tried declaring a new `OleDbConnection conn` inside the `ValidateUserCode()` to but the `conn.State` always returning `"Closed"`.

**UPDATE**

I have a system with 2-layer security feature. 1st is in application and 2nd is on database. If a user logs in to the application, the username and password is also used to **log him/her in to the database**. Now, the scenario is when a user forgot his/her password, we can't determine the `fullname`, `email` and `contact` (which are maintained in the database) of the user. I just know his `usercode`. To determine the contact details, I have to open an active connection using a `DUMMY_ACCOUNT`.

Note that I never maintain the password inside the database.

Comment: (Rollback on invalid edit that should never have been approved.)

Comment: If all you want to do is to close the connection why does the current status matter? Just attempt to close the connection then catch (and ignore) and errors that come from the connection not being open.

Comment: Hmmm.. I got your point but for security purposes, I really want to determine if there is an existing connection for `DUMMY_ACCOUNT`. If there is an existing connection therefore I have to close that connection to give way for the `MAIN_ACCOUNT`.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to accomplish?  What do you mean by "an existing connection for DUMMY_ACCOUNT"?  A user with an active session connected to the Oracle database?  This is OK unless MAIN_ACCOUNT wants to connect?  What happens if you have more than one connection from DUMMY_ACCOUNT?  For me, database security should be handled in the database.  More info and I can provide a database solution.

Comment: I have a system with 2-layer security feature. 1st is in application and 2nd is on database. If a user logs in to the application, the username and password is also used to log him/her in to the database. Now, the scenario is when a user forgot his/her password, we can't determine the `fullname`, `email` and `contact` (which are maintained in the database) of the user. We just knew his `usercode`. To determine the contact details, I have to open an active connection using a `DUMMY_ACCOUNT`. Get my point?

Comment: What type of app is this: ASP, Forms, ...     Is this your question:  Before I create a new MAIN_ACCOUNT connection, I want to check if a DUMMY_ACCOUNT connection is still open.  If it is, close it.       What am I missing:  Create connection using DUMMY_ACCOUNT, do database work, close connection.  Why do you even need this check to see if it is open?

Comment: If the connection is open, and the user tries to login again, there would be case that two database connection will exist. The point here is that we manage the permissions per user up to the data level. The `DUMMY_ACCOUNT` is a super user with access(read-only) to all tables while on the other hand, common users have limited access to tables base on there job description. And yes, this is an ASP, Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you call `Close()` in your `finally` block, which means that at any point in your second method, the connection would be closed. Moreover, even if you don't `Close()` it,since `conn` is a local variable in `Connect()`, when you're back in `ValidateUserCode()`, the connection is already up for garbage collection, and when it's `Dispose()`d, it also closes automatically.

I sugges you either make it a member, pass it as an out parameter, return it by the `Connect()` method (and return `null` for failure, or something, if you don't like exceptions)..or redesign the code.

```
private OleDbConnection Connect(string username, string password)
{
    string CONNSTRING = "Provider = MSDAORA; Data Source = ISDQA; User ID = {0}; Password = {1};";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    string strCon = string.Format(CONNSTRING, username, password);
    conn.ConnectionString = strCon;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
            return conn;
    }//try
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblErr.Text = "Connection error";
    }//catch
    finally
    {
        //you don't want to close it here
        //conn.Close();
    }//finally

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm already at home so I'll try it in the office on Wednesday. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I'm not a C# guy, but how does this even work?  Doesn't the conn.Close() in finally close the connection right after it is opened?    I would expect two methods: conn_open and conn_close

Comment: True, I forgot to remove that part from the code (already noted that fact in the explanation).

The second problem (with the original code) is that after you exit the Connect() method, there's no handle to the OleDbConnection object, so it's disposed by the GC, so it's closed anyway.

Comment: @Ulfric: so, did you try it afterall?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this information helps you.

I had similar problem while using OLEDB connection for Excel Reading. I didn't knew the answer. So, just I added a global variable for OleDbConnection initialized to null.

In my method, I used to check that null, if not close it and again open it.

```
        if (con != null)
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        try
        {
            con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("oledbConnection = " + ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("connection open = " + ex.Message + "\n");
        }
```

I could able to continue after this. You can try, if it works for you its good!

Comment: As much as possible I want to make my codes look clean. Such method could jeopardize my programming convention. But thanks for trying.

Comment: I accept ! Would have seen for solution, but we switched from OleDb to Interop as I was not able to read the excel cell formats through OleDb set of calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow the question quite right.  My answer is based on the premise that you want to open/retrieve a connection, take an action, and close/release the connection afterward.

The code you include does not do that well.  Typical DAO code resembles this pseudocode, in my case taken from some boilerplate code I use.

```
public DataSet FetchDataSet(string sql, IDictionary paramHash) {
    var cnn = AcquireConnection();
    var rtnDS = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = sql;

        SetParameters(cmd, paramHash);
        IDbDataAdapter ida = new DataAdapter { SelectCommand = cmd };
        LogSql(sql, paramHash, "FetchDataSet");
        ida.Fill(rtnDS);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DebugWriteLn("Failed to get a value from the db.", ex);
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        ReleaseConnection(cnn);
    }
    return rtnDS;
}
```

Note that the code above is strictly about communicating with the database.  There is no assessment of whether the data is right or wrong.  You might have a DAO that is a subclass of the one that contains the above code, and it might do this:

```
public MyItemType FindSomeValue(long Id)
{
    const string sql = @"SELECT something from somewhere where id=:id";
    var myParams = new Dictionary<string, long> { { "id", Id } };
    var ds = FetchDataSet(sql, myParams);

    return (from DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows
            select new Item
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt64(row["ID"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                Name = row["NAME"].ToString()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

In fact, the above is pseudocode from a DAO implementation that I've used for years.  It makes data access relatively painless.  Note that there is some real code behind those methods like SetParameters (30 - 80 lines or so), and I have a bunch of other protected methods like FetchScalar, ExecuteSQL, etc.

Comment: Whoops - acronym fever!  Data Access Obect.  These are the classes one puts data access code to keep it separate from the business logic of the application.  I first started using it back in my Java days. See the [J2EE pattern](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/DataAccessObject.htm).