# ASP MVC 3 : record in the database using Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to develop an application ASP MVC 3 using the C # language and the Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2005 data.
I want to make records in my database, but I can not because the parametres which i enter ,,,,are taken as NULL (when I put the cursor on the parameters in the statement of Insert (matricule, ...), the editor tells me that they are NULL)

This is the error which the application show :

```
The INSERT statement is in conflict with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Users_Account". The conflict occurred in database "Range" table "dbo.Account", column 'Type_User'.
```

The statement has been terminated.

PS
When I change this statement :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Users(Matricule, Nom_User,PassWord, Type_User )Values('"+Matricule+"','"+Nom_User+"','"+passWord+"','"+Type_User+"')", cn);
```

By this :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Users(Matricule, Nom_User,PassWord, Type_User )Values('user2','anouar','anouar','Admin')", cn);
```

It's working manually that's mean without putting the values in the form

---

Thanks for the answers , I changed the code like this but always the same problem :

```
public int Insert(string Matricule, string Nom_User, string passWord, string Type_User, string ID_UF)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = SWEET-DE396641E \ SQLEXPRESS; User Id = adminUser; Password = adminUser; Initial Catalog = Gamme");
        cn.Open();


        string sqlquery = ("Insert Into Users(Matricule, Nom_User,PassWord, Type_User, ID_UF )Values(@Matricule, @Nom_User, @passWord, @Type_User, @ID_UF)");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cn);


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Matricule", this.Matricule);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nom_User", this.Nom_User);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passWord", this.passWord);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type_User", this.Type_User);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_UF", this.ID_UF);
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

and this the error :
The parameterized query '(@ Matricule nvarchar (4000), @ user_name nvarchar (4000), @ passWord nv' expects parameter @ Club number has not been specified.

Comment: are you sure the form is posting the correct values?

Comment: Add break point, examine the value of `Type_User` in controller. In order to insert `Type_User` value into `Users` table, this value must be available in `Account` table.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing database null values and c# null values. Try sending in DBNull.Value for any null values.

Also, I would recommend that you use parameterized queries. They make your code easier to read and avoids serious security issues (even if this is just homework, it's best to practice safe code).

Something like this (not tested, but the concept is here)...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Users(Matricule, Nom_User,PassWord, Type_User )Values(@Matricule, @Nom_User, @passWord, @Type_User)", cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Matricule", Matricule ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nom_User", Nom_User?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PassWord", PassWord?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type_User ", Type_User ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Nomad101 suggested, you need to be sure your post fields are being populated and that your controller method has the [HttpPost] attribute on it and debug/step into your code to verify the values are populated.

Second, the way you are creating your query is leaving you wide open to hacker attacks.  Never, ever concatenate your parameters into your query.  I notice that Brian posted a description of the correct way as I was typing this.  Additionally, you'll want to learn about the Data Access Object design pattern I alluded to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098361/how-to-determine-an-existing-oracle-database-connection-in-c/16199525#16199525).